# No Cache Options Showing in Rigid Body Simulation

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, cache

I have set the timeline end to 350 frames, but the simulation ends around frame 250. There should be cache settings somewhere in the Rigid Body Simulation settings, but I can't find them. I appreciate your help!

[image: Not Cache Settings available]

Comment: Should be under the Scene properties rather than the Physics Properties in the R/H panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here they are:

scene properties - rigid body world - cache

[image]